Frames took with ELP camera has unknown pixel format at FHD?
I'm trying to take a one frame ever x seconds from my usb camera. Name of the camera is: ELP-USBFHD06H-SFV(5-50).
Code is not 100% done yet, but I'm using it this way right now ↓ (shot fn is called from main.py in a loop)

import cv2
import subprocess

from time import sleep
from collections import namedtuple

from errors import *

class Camera:
    def __init__(self, cam_index, res_width, res_height, pic_format, day_time_exposure_ms, night_time_exposure_ms):
        Resolution = namedtuple("resolution", ["width", "height"])
        self.manual_mode(True)

        self.cam_index = cam_index
        self.camera_resolution = Resolution(res_width, res_height)
        self.picture_format = pic_format
        self.day_time_exposure_ms = day_time_exposure_ms
        self.night_time_exposure_ms = night_time_exposure_ms

        self.started: bool = False
        self.night_mode = False

        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.cam_index, cv2.CAP_V4L2)
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, self.camera_resolution.width)
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, self.camera_resolution.height)
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*self.picture_format))

    

    def start(self):
        sleep(1)
        if not self.cap.isOpened():
            return CameraCupError()

        self.set_exposure_time(self.day_time_exposure_ms)
        self.set_brightness(0)
        sleep(0.1)
        
        self.started = True



    def shot(self, picture_name, is_night):
        if not self.started:
            return InitializationError()

        self.configure_mode(is_night)

        # Clear buffer
        for _ in range(5):
            ret, _ = self.cap.read()

        ret, frame = self.cap.read()

        sleep(0.1)

        if ret:
            print(picture_name)
            cv2.imwrite(picture_name, frame)
            return True

        else:
            print("No photo")
            return False


    
    def release(self):
        self.set_exposure_time(156)
        self.set_brightness(0)
        self.manual_mode(False)
        self.cap.release()



    def manual_mode(self, switch: bool):
        if switch:
            subprocess.run(["v4l2-ctl", "--set-ctrl=auto_exposure=1"])
        else:
            subprocess.run(["v4l2-ctl", "--set-ctrl=auto_exposure=3"])
        sleep(1)

    
    
    def configure_mode(self, is_night):
        if is_night == self.night_mode:
            return

        if is_night:
            self.night_mode = is_night
            self.set_exposure_time(self.night_time_exposure_ms)
            self.set_brightness(64)
        else:
            self.night_mode = is_night
            self.set_exposure_time(self.day_time_exposure_ms)
            self.set_brightness(0)
        sleep(0.1)



    def set_exposure_time(self, ms: int):
        ms = int(ms)
        default_val = 156

        if ms < 1 or ms > 5000:
            ms = default_val

        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, ms)



    def set_brightness(self, value: int):
        value = int(value)
        default_val = 0

        if value < -64 or value > 64:
            value = default_val

        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS, value)

Here are settings for the camera (yaml file)
camera:
  camera_index: 0
  res_width: 1920
  res_height: 1080
  picture_format: "MJPG"
  day_time_exposure_ms: 5
  night_time_exposure_ms: 5000
  photos_format: "jpg"


I do some configs like set manual mode for the camera, change exposure/brightness and saving frame.
Also the camera is probably catching the frames to the buffer (it is not saving latest frame in real time: it's more laggish), so I have to clear buffer every time. like this
        # Clear buffer from old frames
        for _ in range(5):
            ret, _ = self.cap.read()
        
        # Get a new frame
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()

What I really don't like, but I could find a better way (tldr: setting buffer for 1 frame doesn't work on my camera).
Frames saved this method looks good with 1920x1080 resolution. BUT when I try to run ffmpeg command to make a timelapse from saved jpg file like this
ffmpeg -framerate 20 -pattern_type glob -i "*.jpg" -c:v libx264 output.mp4

I got an error like this one
[image2 @ 0x555609c45240] Could not open file : 08:59:20.jpg
[image2 @ 0x555609c45240] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mjpeg, none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, image2, from '*.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 20 fps, 20 tbr, 20 tbn
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Also when I try to copy the files from Linux to Windows I get some weird copy failing error and option to skip the picture. But even when I press the skip button, the picture is copied and can be opened. I'm not sure what is wrong with the format, but the camera is supporting MPEG at 1920x1080.
>>> v4l2-ctl --all

Driver Info:
        Driver name      : uvcvideo
        Card type        : H264 USB Camera: USB Camera
        Bus info         : usb-xhci-hcd.1-1
        Driver version   : 6.6.51
        Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
                Video Capture
                Metadata Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps      : 0x04200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
Media Driver Info:
        Driver name      : uvcvideo
        Model            : H264 USB Camera: USB Camera
        Serial           : 2020032801
        Bus info         : usb-xhci-hcd.1-1
        Media version    : 6.6.51
        Hardware revision: 0x00000100 (256)
        Driver version   : 6.6.51
Interface Info:
        ID               : 0x03000002
        Type             : V4L Video
Entity Info:
        ID               : 0x00000001 (1)
        Name             : H264 USB Camera: USB Camera
        Function         : V4L2 I/O
        Flags            : default
        Pad 0x0100000d   : 0: Sink
          Link 0x0200001a: from remote pad 0x1000010 of entity 'Extension 4' (Video Pixel Formatter): Data, Enabled, Immutable
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
Format Video Capture:
        Width/Height      : 1920/1080
        Pixel Format      : 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG)
        Field             : None
        Bytes per Line    : 0
        Size Image        : 4147789
        Colorspace        : sRGB
        Transfer Function : Default (maps to sRGB)
        YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default (maps to ITU-R 601)
        Quantization      : Default (maps to Full Range)
        Flags             :
Crop Capability Video Capture:
        Bounds      : Left 0, Top 0, Width 1920, Height 1080
        Default     : Left 0, Top 0, Width 1920, Height 1080
        Pixel Aspect: 1/1
Selection Video Capture: crop_default, Left 0, Top 0, Width 1920, Height 1080, Flags:
Selection Video Capture: crop_bounds, Left 0, Top 0, Width 1920, Height 1080, Flags:
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
        Capabilities     : timeperframe
        Frames per second: 15.000 (15/1)
        Read buffers     : 0

User Controls

                     brightness 0x00980900 (int)    : min=-64 max=64 step=1 default=0 value=64
                       contrast 0x00980901 (int)    : min=0 max=64 step=1 default=32 value=32
                     saturation 0x00980902 (int)    : min=0 max=128 step=1 default=56 value=56
                            hue 0x00980903 (int)    : min=-40 max=40 step=1 default=0 value=0
        white_balance_automatic 0x0098090c (bool)   : default=1 value=1
                          gamma 0x00980910 (int)    : min=72 max=500 step=1 default=100 value=100
                           gain 0x00980913 (int)    : min=0 max=100 step=1 default=0 value=0
           power_line_frequency 0x00980918 (menu)   : min=0 max=2 default=1 value=1 (50 Hz)
                                0: Disabled
                                1: 50 Hz
                                2: 60 Hz
      white_balance_temperature 0x0098091a (int)    : min=2800 max=6500 step=1 default=4600 value=4600 flags=inactive
                      sharpness 0x0098091b (int)    : min=0 max=6 step=1 default=3 value=3
         backlight_compensation 0x0098091c (int)    : min=0 max=2 step=1 default=1 value=1

Camera Controls

                  auto_exposure 0x009a0901 (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=1 (Manual Mode)
                                1: Manual Mode
                                3: Aperture Priority Mode
         exposure_time_absolute 0x009a0902 (int)    : min=1 max=5000 step=1 default=156 value=5000
     exposure_dynamic_framerate 0x009a0903 (bool)   : default=0 value=0

I also tried to save the picture using ffmpeg in a case something is not right with opencv like this:
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 23 -t 00:01:00 output.mp4


It is saving the picture but also changing its format
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x555659ed92b0] The V4L2 driver changed the video from 1920x1080 to 800x600
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x555659ed92b0] The driver changed the time per frame from 1/30 to 1/15

But the format looks right when set it back to FHD using v4l2

>>> v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video0 --set-fmt-video=width=1920,height=1080,pixelformat=MJPG
>>> v4l2-ctl --get-fmt-video

Format Video Capture:
        Width/Height      : 1920/1080
        Pixel Format      : 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG)
        Field             : None
        Bytes per Line    : 0
        Size Image        : 4147789
        Colorspace        : sRGB
        Transfer Function : Default (maps to sRGB)
        YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default (maps to ITU-R 601)
        Quantization      : Default (maps to Full Range)
        Flags             :

I'm not sure what could be wrong with the format/camera and I don't think I have enough information to figure it out.
I tried to use ffmpeg instead of opencv and also change a few settings in opencv's cup config.

I'm not sure what your question really is? Is it about your OpenCV code? Or about capturing video with ffmpeg? Or about assembling frames post-capture with ffmpeg?  Or about copying files to Windows? Or about buffering?

The most ideal answer would be for the question "why is opencv saving frames this way and how could I make it save the way it doesn't  do some weird formatting stuffs at FHD frames"

So, what weird way is OpenCV saving frames? Can you view the frames with your standard utilities that come with your OS?

Yes, I can open it with standard picture viewer after pressing the skip button at copy as I described above. My concern is more about ffmpeg as I would like to process this pictures to timelapse after saving them. So I would like to have them saved proper to be able to process them after

you don't need opencv for any of this. stick with ffmpeg. and list the supported modes of the camera, with ffmpeg.

ffmpeg is not saving files in FHD  The V4L2 driver changed the video from 1920x1080 to 800x600

list them all. literally list them all. there's a wiki page for ffmpeg explaining how to do it. you might have to specify more properties.

Got it. Problem was with the name of saved .jpg files.
From 11:50:45.jpg to 11-50-45.jpg did the trick.
